# Can't run multiple tests inside a load test

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2013, load-testing

I am setting up a load test with multiple web performance tests.

I want one user to run each test. I can't have multiple users run the same test.

I have 10 tests, and I want them all to be run at the same time (i.e. simulating peak load).

When I run my load test only 1 of the tests gets loaded.

Here's my configuration:

- I have 10 web performance tests defined that I've added to a load
  test.
- I have set the "Test Mix Model" to be based on the "total number of
  tests".
- I have allocated each test to have 10% distribution.
- I set the user count to 10 (constant load).

Comment: Do you get one test running ten times? Have you tried the other test mix models? One alternative is to create ten scenarios, each with one user and one test. However, I would expect changing to a different test mix to work.

Comment: @AdrianHHH: I've been trying "total number of tests". I tried "based on number of virtual users" ... it's not exactly what I had in mind, but I think I can get by with it.

Comment: Have you found an answer for your question? If yes then please write it up here. If not then please [edit] the question to make it clearer so that it might be answered.